# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre las cookies y sessionStorage/localStorage?

Tags: javascript, session, cookies

Entiendo la diferencia entre localStorage y sessionStorage, pero ¿cual es la diferencia entre cookies vs local/session? 
¿Cual tiene mas seguridad, ventajas, etc.? ¿Cual es mejor utilizar?

Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**LocalStorage**
La información perdura hasta que limpias caché e información local.
Puedes almacenar toneladas de información, obviamente tu navegador consumirá más memoria. La seguridad es del propio navegador, muy fuerte a decir verdad.

**Session Storage**
La información es almacenada hasta que se cierra el navegador o la pestaña.
Puede almacenar más información que una cookie.

**Cookies**
Almacenan poca información y perdura el tiempo que les definas al crearlas, una de las ventajas es que la cookie la puedes agarrar fácilmente en el front-end y en el back-end (Sin tener que pasarlas por un AJAX por ejemplo si quisieras usar la información del LocalStorage o SessionStorage, ya que sólo vive en el front-end esa información)
La seguridad es limitada, amenos que se configure como httpsonly

**Session Variables**
Para mi gusto son las mejores al momento de hacer Apps, las variables de sesión son controladas y creadas por el back-end, aquí no interviene Javascript ni el navegador. La seguridad de estas va ligada a la seguridad del servidor.

¿Qué usaría? A decir verdad depende de lo que quieras conseguir y desarrollar.